# Calling a function directly from Ionic tab - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, tabs

I am trying to create my first App with Ionic. I have a few tabs as defined in app.js file.

```
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('tab.audioplayer', {
      url: '/audioplayer',
      views: {
        'tab-audioplayer': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-audioplayer.html',
          controller: 'ExampleController'
        }
      }
    })
```

Here in the last tab, I do not want to open a new page like tab-audioplayer.html as currently shown. Instead, I want to call a function say MyFunction() residing in "ChatsCtrl" controller (the previous one), which does some value assignments. As I am new, I don't know how to call a function instead of opening a tab, when the tab icon is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the ion-tab directive in your template, but just use an `<a>` tag and put an `ng-click` on there - it should fit alright within your `<ion-tabs>`container, and just style accordingly (can give it `.tab-item`). I believe the `ion-tab` directive prevents any other actions from happening registered to the click event.

Comment: Thanks @premiumFrye. I have just done that, putting the <a> as second item. It did work, but it appeared as tab # 1 instead of two in sequence. Any idea to fit that at the right place? Others tabs are still <ion-tab>

Comment: I think its too tricky. To gain full control I have decided to use Blank template so that I am able to do whatever I feel like.

Comment: Sure, unless you need the independent history of each tab, you could just replace all your `ion-tab`s with `<a class="ion-tab">` and do whatever you want with each tab.

Comment: That's right. I will need to maintain history manually. Thanks anyway for responding.